# IntelliJ - - How do apply entire file as a change?

Tags: git, rubymine, intellij-15

The git diff view allows me to see the two different revisions of the same file.  It also allows me to pick individual changes and apply them from the other revision to mine.  I do that by pressing the >> button between them.  BUT, when the change is either creating or deleting an entire file, only that file shows up.  There is no >> button!

How do I apply the change if it's a deletion or creation of a file?  For example, the other branch has a new file F.  I just want F ported to my current branch.  How can I use the **RubyMine's "Git Compare to Another Branch" interface** to achieve that? (I already know how to do it in shell)

[picture of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl7Z4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

To Get a file from another branch, you can use Show Diff with the Working Tree action from Branches popup (in earlier versions, this is the Files tab of the Compare with current dialog.)

[image]

And from there call Get from Branch

[image]

It is not available when comparing individual files - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156485.